# Why running clamtk on 12.04 with kernel-update of today crashes the system?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, gdm, clamav

I am performing `clamtk` - virusscan as usual (at a friends computer with 12.04 - updated today):

```
sudo clamtk
```

Then normal scanning of all files. When reaching certain file, it crashes with logout to gdm-login-window.

Should I use clamtk-frontend only as normal user?

As a normal user the same happens again - after scanning first 99 files of whole file-system.

When one time click on gdm-user then it crashes again, then back to gdm.

Again click on gdm-user and login works.

---

from Terminal with command clamtk
it is running a bit longer - but still crashes and logout at once
into gdm ???

I found for to report crash:

```
apport-retrace
```

which is not installed by default (contrary to earlier Ubuntu-Versions).

made then:

```
apt-get install --reinstall clamtk
```

and

```
apt-get install --reinstall gdm
```

now I make reboot (am back soon ... )

no change ... still crashes. then I tried

```
apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
```

(suiting packages to installation)

but it is refused because of too many collisions ???
(on different machines was these packages to reinstall no problem ?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should typically run clamtk as a regular user.  Also, if the problem is not fixed by the linux-headers-generic answer above, please run clamtk from the commandline (just type

```
clamtk
```

and post back any errors or messages upon the crash.

Answer (score 0):

related hint on the right side gave me this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/32060/2-6-35-28-kernel-update-breaks-xorg?rq=1

It seems that linux-headers-generic were missing when kernel updated today, but
they are needed when nvidia-files are substituted too by newer files ...
... this causes the crash ? - right ?

Comment: If you suspect `linux-headers-generic` were missing, try `sud apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is solved by something completely different (at 12.04 LTS 2 of my friend) :

In "system settings" then "brightness and lock" there time should be set to
30 minutes and lock should stay "switched off".

There the default-settings are not correct and causes the crash
into gdm ?

But clamtk is still crashing ?

Now it seems that 13.04 has the same at some installations of other Ubuntu-Users.