# Kubuntu 13.04 Live USB works, graphics crash when installed

Tags: boot, ati, graphics, flicker

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 13.04 on my laptop from a live USB. The live USB works fine, graphics, wireless etc. It all works. Installation works as well, but when I try to start the newly installed Kubuntu from the hard drive I first get a flashing Kubuntu logo, then just flickering lines, mostly white.

From that point I can't switch to a terminal or do anything other than the MagicSysRq combo. The same thing happens if I start with xforcevesa.
If I start with nomodeset or radeon.modeset=0, I just end up with a black screen where the MagicSysRq combo doesn't work, but a quick press on the power button shuts the computer off immediately which tells me the kernel crashed.

The computer is a Dell Studio 1555 laptop with an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4570 graphics card.

I have reinstalled without updates so that only packages from the live USB were installed.
How can the live USB work, but not the installed version?
Thank you for any help!

EDIT: To clarify, I never get past the kernel loading after installing to the hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the system to boot by physically connecting to the internet (with an ethernet cable) and using the recovery root terminal to install the fglrx driver. That allowed me to get into the system. From there, I realized the fglrx driver no longer supports my graphics card so I had to use this: https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx
After installing fglrx-legacy everything seems to run smoothly.

Hopefully, this will be of use to someone else.

Comment: So, I assume there's a major bug in the free drivers? I'm experiencing this issue as well and your solution helped a lot. Has anyone reported this bug already?

Answer (score 0):

how is it crashing ?
Is Desktop crashing then returning to login-manager ?

for this was similiar like here ? :

[Why running clamtk on 12.04 with kernel-update of today crashes the system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299580/why-running-clamtk-on-12-04-with-kernel-update-of-today-crashes-the-system)

I think it is to do too - with after updating of kernel-files and xserver-xorg-files.

The default settings of "brightness and lock" are then not correct at 13.04 too ?

Try "system-settings" in your desktop - go there to "brightness and lock" and adjust
it too 30 minutes - and lock should stay switched off.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear! After installing to the hard drive, I never get past the kernel loading. Graphics, or the kernel, crashes before the login screen.

Comment: is it PC or notebook ? - if PC - have you built yourself ? every contact of technical parts correctly set-in-its-place ?

Comment: It's a PC laptop. I've run Ubuntu on it for years and I'm dual-booting with Fedora 17 and Windows Vista so there is nothing wrong with the hardware.